# Customizing LifeRay portlet using jspf hook

Tags: liferay, hook, customization, portlet, jsp-fragments

i need to customize the create account portlet, i want to hide the filed "middle name" , but that field exists under the file /html/portlet/login/create_account_user_name.jspf, using the hook for customizing jsp pages didn't work because that file is a "jspf" not a "jsp" and it's not displayed in the eclipse window of jsp files available for hook change

Have someone a solution for that situation?

Content of create_account_user_name.jspf :

```
<aui:input autoFocus="<%= windowState.equals(WindowState.MAXIMIZED) %>" model="<%= User.class %>" name="firstName" />

<aui:input model="<%= User.class %>" name="middleName" />

<aui:input model="<%= User.class %>" name="lastName">
    <c:if test="<%= PrefsPropsUtil.getBoolean(company.getCompanyId(), PropsKeys.USERS_LAST_NAME_REQUIRED, PropsValues.USERS_LAST_NAME_REQUIRED) %>">
        <aui:validator name="required" />
    </c:if>
</aui:input>
```

Content of create_account.jsp :

```
<%@ include file="/html/portlet/login/init.jsp" %>

<%
String redirect = ParamUtil.getString(request, "redirect");

String openId = ParamUtil.getString(request, "openId");
boolean male = ParamUtil.getBoolean(request, "male", true);

Calendar birthdayCalendar = CalendarFactoryUtil.getCalendar();

birthdayCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
birthdayCalendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
birthdayCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1970);
%>

<portlet:actionURL secure="<%= PropsValues.COMPANY_SECURITY_AUTH_REQUIRES_HTTPS || request.isSecure() %>" var="createAccountURL">
        <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/login/create_account" />
</portlet:actionURL>

<aui:form action="<%= createAccountURL %>" method="post" name="fm">
        <aui:input name="saveLastPath" type="hidden" value="<%= false %>" />
        <aui:input name="<%= Constants.CMD %>" type="hidden" value="<%= Constants.ADD %>" />
        <aui:input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="<%= redirect %>" />
        <aui:input name="openId" type="hidden" value="<%= openId %>" />

        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= AddressCityException.class %>" message="please-enter-a-valid-city" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= AddressStreetException.class %>" message="please-enter-a-valid-street" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= AddressZipException.class %>" message="please-enter-a-valid-postal-code" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= CaptchaMaxChallengesException.class %>" message="maximum-number-of-captcha-attempts-exceeded" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= CaptchaTextException.class %>" message="text-verification-failed" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= CompanyMaxUsersException.class %>" message="unable-to-create-user-account-because-the-maximum-number-of-users-has-been-reached" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= ContactFirstNameException.class %>" message="please-enter-a-valid-first-name" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= ContactFullNameException.class %>" message="please-enter-a-valid-first-middle-and-last-name" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= ContactLastNameException.class %>" message="please-enter-a-valid-last-name" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= DuplicateOpenIdException.class %>" message="a-user-with-that-open-id-already-exists" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= DuplicateUserEmailAddressException.class %>" message="the-email-address-you-requested-is-already-taken" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= DuplicateUserIdException.class %>" message="the-user-id-you-requested-is-already-taken" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= DuplicateUserScreenNameException.class %>" message="the-screen-name-you-requested-is-already-taken" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= EmailAddressException.class %>" message="please-enter-a-valid-email-address" />

        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= GroupFriendlyURLException.class %>">

                <%
                GroupFriendlyURLException gfurle = (GroupFriendlyURLException)errorException;
                %>

                <c:if test="<%= gfurle.getType() == GroupFriendlyURLException.DUPLICATE %>">
                        <liferay-ui:message key="the-screen-name-you-requested-is-associated-with-an-existing-friendly-url" />
                </c:if>
        </liferay-ui:error>

        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= NoSuchCountryException.class %>" message="please-select-a-country" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= NoSuchListTypeException.class %>" message="please-select-a-type" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= NoSuchRegionException.class %>" message="please-select-a-region" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= PhoneNumberException.class %>" message="please-enter-a-valid-phone-number" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= RequiredFieldException.class %>" message="please-fill-out-all-required-fields" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= ReservedUserEmailAddressException.class %>" message="the-email-address-you-requested-is-reserved" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= ReservedUserIdException.class %>" message="the-user-id-you-requested-is-reserved" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= ReservedUserScreenNameException.class %>" message="the-screen-name-you-requested-is-reserved" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= TermsOfUseException.class %>" message="you-must-agree-to-the-terms-of-use" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= UserEmailAddressException.class %>" message="please-enter-a-valid-email-address" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= UserIdException.class %>" message="please-enter-a-valid-user-id" />

        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= UserPasswordException.class %>">

                <%
                UserPasswordException upe = (UserPasswordException)errorException;
                %>

                <c:if test="<%= upe.getType() == UserPasswordException.PASSWORD_CONTAINS_TRIVIAL_WORDS %>">
                        <liferay-ui:message key="that-password-uses-common-words-please-enter-in-a-password-that-is-harder-to-guess-i-e-contains-a-mix-of-numbers-and-letters" />
                </c:if>

                <c:if test="<%= upe.getType() == UserPasswordException.PASSWORD_INVALID %>">
                        <liferay-ui:message key="that-password-is-invalid-please-enter-in-a-different-password" />
                </c:if>

                <c:if test="<%= upe.getType() == UserPasswordException.PASSWORD_LENGTH %>">

                        <%
                        PasswordPolicy passwordPolicy = PasswordPolicyLocalServiceUtil.getDefaultPasswordPolicy(company.getCompanyId());
                        %>

                        <%= LanguageUtil.format(pageContext, "that-password-is-too-short-or-too-long-please-make-sure-your-password-is-between-x-and-512-characters", String.valueOf(passwordPolicy.getMinLength()), false) %>
                </c:if>

                <c:if test="<%= upe.getType() == UserPasswordException.PASSWORD_TOO_TRIVIAL %>">
                        <liferay-ui:message key="that-password-is-too-trivial" />
                </c:if>

                <c:if test="<%= upe.getType() == UserPasswordException.PASSWORDS_DO_NOT_MATCH %>">
                        <liferay-ui:message key="the-passwords-you-entered-do-not-match-each-other-please-re-enter-your-password" />
                </c:if>
        </liferay-ui:error>

        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= UserScreenNameException.class %>" message="please-enter-a-valid-screen-name" />
        <liferay-ui:error exception="<%= WebsiteURLException.class %>" message="please-enter-a-valid-url" />

        <c:if test='<%= SessionMessages.contains(request, "openIdUserInformationMissing") %>'>
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                        <liferay-ui:message key="you-have-successfully-authenticated-please-provide-the-following-required-information-to-access-the-portal" />
                </div>
        </c:if>

        <aui:model-context model="<%= Contact.class %>" />

        <aui:fieldset column="<%= true %>">
                <aui:col width="<%= 50 %>">
                        <%@ include file="/html/portlet/login/create_account_user_name.jspf" %>

                        <c:if test="<%= !PrefsPropsUtil.getBoolean(company.getCompanyId(), PropsKeys.USERS_SCREEN_NAME_ALWAYS_AUTOGENERATE) %>">
                                <aui:input model="<%= User.class %>" name="screenName" />
                        </c:if>

                        <aui:input autoFocus="<%= true %>" model="<%= User.class %>" name="emailAddress">
                                <c:if test="<%= PrefsPropsUtil.getBoolean(company.getCompanyId(), PropsKeys.USERS_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REQUIRED) %>">
                                        <aui:validator name="required" />
                                </c:if>
                        </aui:input>
                </aui:col>

                <aui:col width="<%= 50 %>">
                        <c:if test="<%= PropsValues.LOGIN_CREATE_ACCOUNT_ALLOW_CUSTOM_PASSWORD %>">
                                <aui:input label="password" name="password1" size="30" type="password" value="" />

                                <aui:input label="enter-again" name="password2" size="30" type="password" value="">
                                        <aui:validator name="equalTo">
                                                '#<portlet:namespace />password1'
                                        </aui:validator>
                                </aui:input>
                        </c:if>

                        <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="<%= PrefsPropsUtil.getBoolean(company.getCompanyId(), PropsKeys.FIELD_ENABLE_COM_LIFERAY_PORTAL_MODEL_CONTACT_BIRTHDAY) %>">
                                        <aui:input name="birthday" value="<%= birthdayCalendar %>" />
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                        <aui:input name="birthdayMonth" type="hidden" value="<%= Calendar.JANUARY %>" />
                                        <aui:input name="birthdayDay" type="hidden" value="1" />
                                        <aui:input name="birthdayYear" type="hidden" value="1970" />
                                </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>

                        <c:if test="<%= PrefsPropsUtil.getBoolean(company.getCompanyId(), PropsKeys.FIELD_ENABLE_COM_LIFERAY_PORTAL_MODEL_CONTACT_MALE) %>">
                                <aui:select label="gender" name="male">
                                        <aui:option label="male" value="1" />
                                        <aui:option label="female" selected="<%= !male %>" value="0" />
                                </aui:select>
                        </c:if>

                        <c:if test="<%= PropsValues.CAPTCHA_CHECK_PORTAL_CREATE_ACCOUNT %>">
                                <portlet:resourceURL var="captchaURL">
                                        <portlet:param name="struts_action" value="/login/captcha" />
                                </portlet:resourceURL>

                                <liferay-ui:captcha url="<%= captchaURL %>" />
                        </c:if>
                </aui:col>
        </aui:fieldset>

        <aui:button-row>
                <aui:button type="submit" />
        </aui:button-row>
</aui:form>

<liferay-util:include page="/html/portlet/login/navigation.jsp" />
```

Comment: Add jsp file in your hook as it is, which includes your jspf

Comment: Yes i did this, i included the jsp file /html/portlet/login/create_account.jsp but that jsp file does not have the aui tag representing the field "Middle name". that tag is in the jspf file not the jsp one

Comment: rename jspf file and refer that new name in create_account.jsp

Comment: That tip works too Pankaj Kathiriya Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just copy the original file /html/portlet/login/create_account_user_name.jspf inside your docroot/custom_jsp/html/portlet/login/ directory. Despite what eclipse shows to you, any jsp/jspf of your hook will replace the original liferay file.

I successfully edited file /html/portlet/users_admin/user/details_user_name.jspf (i disabled field modifications for users coming from ldap).

Please note that in liferay-hook.xml the only directive you can set for jsp overriding is

```
<custom-jsp-dir>/custom_jsp</custom-jsp-dir>
```

You wont need to specify all jsp files, just your root directory